# How can I get CPU speed as *.** GHz?

Tags: system-tray, monitoring, output, cpufreq

I currently use `indicator-sysmonitor` to see my CPU and RAM percentage in my system tray. But I would like to add my CPU speed. Now I know there are multiple commands (e.g. `lscpu | grep "CPU-frequentie"` (Dutch) ) to get the CPU speed but I want in a way like this: 2.85 GHz.

How do I alter an output like 2850.153 to something like the 2.85 GHz?

Comment: Have you tried `indicator-cpufreq`?

Comment: Yes I've tried it, but I only get a symbol and when I clock on it, I can choose between "power save" and something else. I don't see any hertz.

Comment: Would you be good with a bash script?

Comment: @AndroidDev just did that, I've posted a working script as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, I made a script that returns something like 3.12GHz or 2.80GHz. It forces the output to be X.XXGHz.

First, I used a script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39114732/6260745).

Then, I made this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

speed=$(div $(lscpu | grep CPU-frequentie | awk '{print $3;}' | cut -d'.' -f1) 1000 | awk '{print substr($1,2); }' | cut -c -4)

if [ ${#speed} -ge 4 ]; then :
else speed=$speed"0"
fi

echo $speed"GHz"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following a shorter example:

```
#!/bin/sh
lscpu |awk -F : '($1=="CPU MHz") {printf "%3.2fGHz\n", $2/1000}'
```

Note that, on my system, using an AMD CPU and lscpu version 2.27.1 on ubuntu server 16.04 (64 bit) I have lines in the output as follows:

```
CPU MHz:               4000.000
CPU max MHz:           4000.0000
CPU min MHz:           1400.0000
```

The awk command uses ":" as the field separator. It looks for the line starting "CPU MHz" and then simply prints the value over 1000 (convert MHz to GHz) using 3.2 format -- three significant figures with two decimal places.

From your question, you appear to be looking for "CPU-frequentie" is the lscpu output. I don't know what the output of your lscpu looks like, but I assume that you might need to substitute "CPU-frequentie" for "CPU MHz" in the awk line

For completeness, the output I get on my system is:

```
4.00GHz
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Was thinking the same thing. The awk power.

Comment: awk is indeed pretty helpful here. And your output is CPU MHz, CPU max MHz and CPU min MHz, my output is the same but the first is CPU-frequentie (MHz) instead of CPU MHz