# Is there a CPU monitor widget showing CPU frequency in GHz?

Tags: cpu, monitoring, cpufreq

I have Kubuntu 18.10 with KDE Plasma 5.14.4 on a Lenovo laptop.

Is there a CPU monitor widget showing CPU frequency in GHz?

I would like a live monitoring from a widget in system tray in GHz.

If possible, how to make Psensor showing CPU frequency in GHz or similar?

I want to monitor CPU frequency in GHz from system tray and do not want to monitor CPU usage in percentage like the duplicate.

Comment: But doesn't GHz have to do with frequency and not with usage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get CPU speed as \*.\*\* GHz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877982/how-can-i-get-cpu-speed-as-ghz)

Comment: Changed usage with frequency, thanks. As I understand from the possible duplicate, it is monitoring from terminal and not from system tray?

Comment: I already have indicator-cpufreq installed and changed the governor to performance. It does not monitor my CPU frequency. It gives me the option to changes the frequencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For CPU usage:**

```
sudo apt install indicator-cpufreq
```

and also try this

```
sudo apt install indicator-multiload
```

A small script for monitoring frequency.

```
while true
do 
    echo $(lscpu | grep MHz)
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Neither gives me CPU frequency display. `indicator-cpufreq` only shows me "governor" and "performance". The other one just doesn't show anything. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Penghe Geng Edited and added a small script.

Comment: also, `watch 'lscpu | grep MHz'`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command with the [Command Output Widget](https://store.kde.org/p/1166510/).

```
lscpu |awk -F : '($1=="CPU MHz") {printf "%3.2fGHz\n", $2/1000}'
```